# Get list of jobs with 3 consecutive failures

Tags: sql, oracle

The failure_count isn't reliable in Oracle, so I'm looking for the SQL to query `SYS.ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`.

For starters, here's the table that contains the run details, in this query I've added a hardcoded job name, and just get last 3 runs.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SYS.ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
WHERE JOB_NAME = 'MY JOB' 
ORDER BY LOG_ID 
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

What I want to do is combine this with a query to `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` that can for each job, check last 3 runs and if the `STATUS` for all 3 is `'FAILED'` then return something.

I'm just not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to assign a rank to each log entry within groups of records havings the same `job_name`.

If you just want the names of jobs whose last 3 runs failed, then you can use aggregation in the outer query. The `HAVING` clause filters in the relevant records.

```
SELECT job_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        job_name, 
        status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY log_date DESC) rn 
    FROM sys.all_scheduler_job_run_details
) x
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY job_name
HAVING
    MIN(status) = 'FAILED'
    AND MAX(status) = 'FAILED'
```

NB:

- I think that you do not need to bring in system view `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` to obtain the expected result (`ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` has all the information we need)
- I suspect that you want to sort records using `log_date` instead of `log_id`

---

On the other hand, if you need to entire log entries for the jobs that meet the criteria, then you would need an additional level of subquery, like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        x.*, 
        MAX(status) OVER(PARTITION BY job_name) max_status,
        MIN(status) OVER(PARTITION BY job_name) min_status
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            j.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY log_date DESC) rn 
        FROM sys.all_scheduler_job_run_details j
    ) x
    WHERE rn <= 3
) y 
WHERE 
    max_status = 'FAILED'
    AND min_status = 'FAILED'
```